# how to remove scroll bar from android.support.v4.app.ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have an Android Application with `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`
I do not want the list to display its scroll bar
if i was specifying a list in XML i could use scroll bars = "none"

what options does ListFragment expose to get the same result?

My Min SDK = 11, Target SDK = 17

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`getListView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#getListView%28%29) to get the current `ListView` and hide the scrollbars :

```
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
listView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Dalmas, thanks very much, i only looked for methods setScroll*() never thought to look for SetVert* setHoriz*

Comment: Make sure you override the onViewCreated method.